# How to get height of an image when bootstrap modal is show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Please help me to write jQuery for this:

I have this HTML source in bootstrap modal:

```
<div class="product-preview nospace">
    <div class="product-thumb-list product-image-list">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/products/product-1-l.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/products/product-22-l.jpg" alt="product-thumb">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/products/product-2-l.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/products/product-22-l.jpg" alt="product-thumb">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/products/product-3-l.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/products/product-33-l.jpg" alt="product-thumb">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/products/product-4-l.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/products/product-44-l.jpg" alt="product-thumb">
    </div>
    <div class="product-thumb product-image">
        <img class="img-responsive zoom-image" src="images/products/product-1-l.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/products/product-11-l.jpg" alt="product-img">
    </div>
</div>
```

and in JS I write this:

```
$('.modal-quickview').on('show.bs.modal', function () {

    $('.zoom-image').click("bind", function() {
        var height =$(this).css('height');

        alert(height);
     });
});
```

Now I want to get height of image but with no action like click.

How can I modify that script like?. Anyone please help me? I'm a newbie in JS.

Comment: You may also try a course or book on JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$('.modal-quickview').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    var height = $(this).find('.zoom-image').css('height');
});
```

If you don't want to get the css height value but the actual image height, use: `$(this).find('.zoom-image').height();` instead.

**UPDATE**

I would suggest the same as Keeper. Try `shown.bs.modal` instead. The reason why you see 0px will most probably be because your image is not visible at the moment you are trying to determine it's height. If you use the `shown.bs.modal` event, the modal is already visible and the images therefore have a determinable height.

[**Working Example**](http://www.bootply.com/2gWG3A0qG5)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but I don't know why when I alert(height); it says : 0px; Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: you have to use the event show**n**.bs.modal. It definitely works. See my working example.

Comment: thanks all for helping me, I do like that but when alert(height) it always says 0

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the *.css()*-function on the selector like this:

```
var height = $(".zoom-image").css("height");
```

Please note that using a class as a jQuery selector will most likley return more than one item (if multiple tags have the *zoom-image*-class and *.css()* will then return the height of the first returned item. It might be better to have an unique ID attached to the image and work with that ID. Like this:

```
<img id="displayedImage" class="img-responsive zoom-image" (...)>
```

and then use the ID-selector:

```
var height = $("#displayedImage").css("height");
```

*Note:* You should have a look at the difference between *.css("height")* and *.height()*. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/height/).

Edit: Maybe your problem is the use of *show.bs.modal*, you could try *show**n**.bs.modal* instead. See [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I have tried but with image in normal div is get height right, but with this image in bootstrap modal so it always returns 0px first. I don't know how to write further more for that.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of getting the height is to calculate it on click of the image:

```
$('.modal-quickview').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.zoom-image').click("bind", function() {
        var height =$(this).css('height');
        alert(height);
    });
});
```

I don't want to have to click on the image to get the height value, however, this may help someone else who wants to do it that way!